# Shadowbox Jquery Only Showing dimmed background

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

I have inserted Shadow box into a website on the page load using the unchanged usage code from the shaowboax website, but all it seems to load is the dimmed black background that usually sits behind the pop-up.

This is the JS and references I'm using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
    // let's skip the automatic setup because we don't have any
    // properly configured link elements on the page
    skipSetup: true
});

window.onload = function() {

    // open a welcome message as soon as the window loads
    Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '<div id="welcome-msg">Test</div>',
        player:     "html",
        title:      "Welcome",
        height:     552,
        width:      514
    });

};
</script>
```

I've already tried using different players, chaging the content in the popup, loading an older version of Showbox and changing the location of the script and stylesheet. I'm using the Jquery download version of Shadowbox and the script tags are placed inside `<body>` tags. Does any one have any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle.net demonstrating your problem and we'll try and help.

Comment: Hi, I think this should do it, it's not working at all there though which makes me think I messed up the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/W3R3W0LF666/4dgSr/

Comment: Yep getting a whole load of 404 errors for your shadowbox js and css references.  Please fix, also you had to add jQuery which I've done for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/4dgSr/1/) This is a great example of why I encourage people to try and make it work on a fiddle as it's likely that the answer to your original question lies in incorrect paths to various resources but cannot tell without any debug output from your browser.

Comment: The references on the site are fine though, I just can't publish them because of confidentiality. First thing I checked.

Comment: There are a whole host of other reasons unfortunately why this might not be working and without any more than the above code from the shadowbox website we can't help you as it obviously works there.  Perhaps set up a dummy page on your site or use dummy data and paste the content here or in a fiddle.  It seems that shadowbox has various versions depending on whether you are using other frameworks and it pulls in other files (which you perhaps haven't got accessible) which it needs when it initiates.